# Exporting Pandas to CSV results in #NAME error in CSV

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF that looks like this:

```
    Words
    +Beverly +Hills
    +Andrea +Johnson
    +Football
```

Exporting this df to a CSV using:

```
  df.to_csv('df.csv', index=False)
```

However, because each word has a '+' before it, excel is reading these cells as an equation resulting in an #NAME error.  I know I can force an ' before the string to have excel read it as plaintext but that results in a leading ' which I do not want.

Suggestions to fix this error on exporting?

Comment: Can you instead do: `df.to_excel('df.xlsx', index=False)`?

Comment: The 'csv' itself is not bad, only Excel's reading of it. You could open the file in a text editor or with some other package. You can also I believe import the cvs to excel as text rather than simply double clicking the file to open it.

Comment: Hey @Bernie,  I tried that -- I keep getting this error ValueError: Installed openpyxl is not supported at this time. Use >=1.6.1 and <2.0.0.  If I were able to fix this issue, what would converting do?

Comment: Are the '+' signs necessary? Why not just strip them out? There is no error on export after all only in the software you are using to read the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataFrame can be written to an xlsx file with no issues using to_excel and the xlsxwriter engine. Maybe that's good enough. However the same issue as you have experienced occurs after converting the xlsx file to cvs format using Excel.

Here is an example of creating the xlsx file:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
data = {'Words': ['+Beverly +Hills', '+Andrea +Johnson', '+Football']}
df = DataFrame(data)
df
Out[2]: 
              Words
0   +Beverly +Hills
1  +Andrea +Johnson
2         +Football

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('df.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()

# contents of df.xlsx are now
#     Words
# 0  +Beverly +Hills
# 1  +Andrea +Johnson
# 2  +Football
```